# How to parse ASN.1 value notation format

Tags: asn.1

I'm working for a company which gets logs in ASN.1 value notation format. I need to setup a parser to extract data from this. I have tried naive regular expressions but I would like to try a method where I could extract data from such files, like a JSON/XML file.

For eg: for a file like this,

```
value Rocket ::= {
  name "Falcon",
  -- use default for the message --
  fuel solid,
  speed mph : 18000,
  payload {
    "Car",
    "GPS"
  }
}
```

I would like to parse this,

A root node  ( Rocket )

A value node (name ) = "Falcon"

Another node which encapsulates an array payload ("Car,"GPS")

How to do this ? Any libraries or methods would be helpful.
How does having a schema for this help in this case ? And how to validate the asn.1 against the schema and extract information from asn1. values ?

Comment: It's slightly vexing that the logs are in ASN.1 value notation, instead of one of the myriad of wire formats like BER, XER, etc. that ASN.1 supports. Could the originators be persuaded to send the logs in one of those wire formats?

Comment: @bazza Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to parse ASN.1 notation like this, would be to use a commercial ASN.1 Tool which supports parsing ASN.1 value notation at runtime (not just at compile time).  Note that you will still need the ASN.1 type definitions for the values, not just the value notation.

One such tool can be obtained from OSS Nokalva (https://www.oss.com), who I work for.  These ASN.1 Tools also support XML Encoding Rules (XER) and JSON Encoding Rule (JER) so that you can produce output in JSON or XML as you desire.  You can try the capability at the free ASN.1 Playground website https://asn1-playground.oss.com to see if the log files you are trying to parse are valid ASN.1 value notation.